# How long takes a multiplier function on FPGA? and is it possible to calculate this time?

Tags: fpga

I have implemented a hardware architecture on FPGA and i use some multiplier function on this architecture ,

I'd like to know is there any way or method on ISE software or hardware (by using chip scope) to calculate the maximum delay time of each section/step?

for example i want to know if i increase the input clock pulse, which sections won't work correctly?

Comment: A 32 bit DSP based multiply needs circa 18 ns on a Spartan 3. Have you applied constraints, so that STA could check your design?

Comment: @Paebbels thanks I applied constraints to some nets,  now i want to compare propagation delay time and execution time and find the speeding up factor between to architectures,

Comment: This is not an easy task. You could use synthesis estmations or level of logic to compare 2 architectures. But synthesis Fmax values are not very accurate. A better way is to use post P&R values from static timing analysis (STA). This reqires at least one timing constraint for the SystemClock. But there is one drawback: Map and P&R stop optimizing if all constraints are met. So if you set Fin = 10MHz it will say OK Fmax is 95 MHz, if you set 100 MHz it will say OK Fmax is 108 MHz ... So it needs a bit of testing to find the real Fmax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the timing report for the design, which can give you delay information about various elements in a requested path.

Based on this you can also get minimum slack information, which then tells you how much you may increase the clock, and you can then change the clock frequency and rerun synthesis to check that it holds timing with the new clock frequency.

Using specific measurement, from for example chip scope, only gives information about that specific chip, on that specific power supply, with that specific data, etc., where the timing engine (Static Timing Analysis (STA)) given you a worst case analysis for design and vendor parameters.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,i checked the STA for increasing the clock frequency,

Comment: i have a question about measuring the time of process execution and propagation delay time in complex process, for example is it possible to measure total execution time in a process that contain some relative condition loops and access internal memory , for example i can implement hardware architecture in 2 methods and i want to know which one is faster than other one ,and then measure the speeding up factor of faster one,

Comment: First, a VHDL process does **not** have an execution time like a function in e.g. C, but instead it describes a hardware circuit that will have a certain delay in a certain implementation e.g. a FPGA.  This is a significant difference between regular programming languages like C, and a hardware description language like VHDL. As you note, then it is possible to implement the same operation in different ways, so you should definitely examine different implementations if delay is a concern.  Make separate compiles for each implementation to ensure best optimizations, instead of both in one.